# How to group rows in SQL with a special condition?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this in my database:

```
+-----------+-------+--------+--------------+
| Person_ID | Month |  Name  |   Special    |
+-----------+-------+--------+--------------+
|       807 |    01 | Smith  | othercontent |
|       807 |    01 | Smith  | othercontent |
|       807 |    02 | Smith  | othercontent |
|       807 |    02 | Smith  | othercontent |
|       807 |    02 | Smith  | content      |
|       807 |    02 | Smith  | othercontent |
|       807 |    03 | Smith  | othercontent |
|       807 |    03 | Smith  | othercontent |
|       807 |    03 | Smith  | othercontent |
|       807 |    04 | Smith  | othercontent |
|       807 |    04 | Smith  | content      |
|       807 |    04 | Smith  | othercontent |
|       981 |    01 | Walker | othercontent |
|       981 |    01 | Walker | othercontent |
|       981 |    02 | Walker | othercontent |
|       981 |    02 | Walker | othercontent |
|       981 |    02 | Walker | content      |
|       981 |    02 | Walker | othercontent |
|       981 |    03 | Walker | othercontent |
|       981 |    03 | Walker | othercontent |
|       981 |    03 | Walker | othercontent |
|       981 |    04 | Walker | othercontent |
|       981 |    04 | Walker | content      |
|       981 |    04 | Walker | othercontent |
+-----------+-------+--------+--------------+
```

I have to write a SQL-Query that selects every month that does not contain "content" at least once.
And it should only give out one line.

So the output should be like this:

```
+-----------+-------+--------+--------------+
| Person_ID | Month |  Name  |   Special    |
+-----------+-------+--------+--------------+
|       807 |    01 | Smith  | othercontent |
|       807 |    03 | Smith  | othercontent |
|       981 |    01 | Walker | othercontent |
|       981 |    03 | Walker | othercontent |
+-----------+-------+--------+--------------+
```

How can I accomplish that with a SQL-Query?
I tried to do that with the group by function, but could not get it working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one row per person/month combination, then use aggregation.  You have use a `having` clause to filter out the `'content'` rows:

```
select person_id, month, name, max(special)
from t
group by person_id, month, name
having sum(case when special = 'content' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: This query works perfectly with SQLite. However if I try to use this in Excel (Data -> "From Other Sources" ->  From Microsoft Query) and run the the SQL-Query, I get a syntax error. The problem seems to be related to the part starting at `having...`. Can you explain what needs to be changed?

Comment: @Robin . . . That might be because `month` is an ODB reserved word.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it does not work even if I change the columnheader to something else. It is stil saying syntax error (missing operator) in query expression `'sum(case when special = 'content' then 1 else 0 end) = 0'`

Comment: @Robin . . . The code is valid SQL Server code.  What is the underlying database?

Comment: it's a SQLite Database and your SQL-Query code worked perfectly in my Database-Browser. For the attempt to run the code in Excel I just copied the table from my original post into an `.xlsx-file` and run the procedure I mentioned in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
select *
from t
where month not in ( select month from t as t2 where t2.special = 'content')
group by person_id, month, name, special
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need

```
select distinct *
from t t1
where not exists(select 1 from t t2 where t1.month=t2.month and t2.special = 'content')
```